# Merging two rails project as one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Consider the situation where two people are working on same rails project but in different machine. One person working on model and controller and another one is working in view. To be more precise, lets say one is working on login/registration control and another one is working on view to the login page (Designing the login page). Now both completed there jobs and they now want to merge both project so that all model, view, and controller can be placed at one. I have a little knowledge on Git and looked for sub tree in git. But still not cleared on the concept. Could please any one suggest me the way I can merge two project in one

Comment: First of all http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 is a good site to learn a little bit about git. Second: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging is what you need in git. Two branches merging into the master.

Comment: No you don't need "branches" or "merging" in git! Git IS a merging system, so just use one 'master' branch. Branches are for teams-of-teams doing complex things (such as the entire Linux kernel). Also, because your two developers use automated tests, you can pass the tests before pushing and after pulling, so you can integrate as often as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use github. It is the best option to work simultaneously on the same project by multiple people. https://www.github.com. You can merge, rollback or backups your project.